# tum_simulator on ROS Hydro

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-hydro, gazebo-ros, tum-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,

i'm trying to install tum_simulator on hydro.
wiki.ros.org/tum_simulator
However, cvg_sim_gazebo_plugins package depends on 'gazebo' package in ros. Ros hydro comes with a pre-installed gazebo but its package name is 'gazebo_ros' so tum_simulator cannot find 'gazebo' package because of its new name. How can i make tum_simulator to see 'gazebo_ros' package as 'gazebo' package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/110881/tum_simulator-on-ros-hydro/) by [lvntbkdmr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9991/lvntbkdmr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-12-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [learningpro](https://answers.ros.org/users/10636/learningpro/) on 2014-01-08**:
have you solved the problem? I come with the same with you,may I know your solution? Thank you.

**Comment by [lvntbkdmr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9991/lvntbkdmr/) on 2014-01-09**:
no, i couldn't use that package with ROS Hydro. i'm using hector_quadrotor instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since its Hydro release, ROS does not have Gazebo inbuilt anymore. Gazebo is now a separate standalone platform for simulations, which can be integrated and used with ROS hydro using the package gazebo_ros_pkgs. For more information you should visit [gazebosim.org](http://gazebosim.org).

---

Originally posted by [mimpho](https://answers.ros.org/users/22438/mimpho/) with karma: 26 on 2015-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1